# NoSuchMethodError javax.validation.Validator.forExecutables() but the Junit works

Tags: validation, aspectj, resteasy, spring-aop, hibernate-validator

Why do I get this exception NoSuchMethodError javax.validation.Validator.forExecutables() when I run the application and the following method is called but the exception is never thrown if I call the method from a JUnit test, it executes perfectly. I'm using Spring AOP 3.2.4 + AspectJ and Hibernate Validator 5.0.1.

It complains that it can't find the forExecutables method. Thanks

```
    @Before("execution(* com.sadc.missioncontrol.api.client.models.workRequest.MaintainTimesheet.getPublicHolidays(..))")
public void validateBeforeGetPublicHolidays(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation
            .buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    ExecutableValidator executableValidator = factory.getValidator()
            .forExecutables();

    mainTimesheet = new MaintainTimesheet();
    Method method = MaintainTimesheet.class.getMethod( "getPublicHolidays", String.class,String.class );
    Set<ConstraintViolation<MaintainTimesheet>> violations = executableValidator.validateParameters(
    mainTimesheet,
    method,
    joinPoint.getArgs()
    );
    System.out.println("Number of Violations: " + violations.size());

}
```

StackTrace:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Validator.forExecutables()Ljavax/validation/executable/ExecutableValidator;
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Validator.forExecutables()Ljavax/validation/executable/ExecutableValidator;
    com.sadc.missioncontrol.api.commons.validations.TimesheetValidationAspect.validateBeforeGetPublicHolidays(TimesheetValidationAspect.java:27)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:603)
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice.before(AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice.java:39)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    com.sadc.missioncontrol.api.client.models.workRequest.MaintainTimesheet$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$985a406e.getPublicHolidays(<generated>)
    com.sadc.missioncontrol.api.client.workServiceWrappers.TimesheetWrapper.getPublicHolidays(TimesheetWrapper.java:77)
    com.sadc.missioncontrol.api.client.TimesheetServiceWorker.handleGetPublicHolidays(TimesheetServiceWorker.java:88)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sadc</groupId>
    <artifactId>MissionControl</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MissionControl</name>
    <url>http://www.company.co.za</url>

    <!-- Remote repositories -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Maven dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils-bean-collections</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.ext.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.39.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.ext.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>juli</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.39.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring AOP + AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven War file generator plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven compiler plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>${env.HOSTNAME}</hostname>
                    <port>9999</port>
                    <username> admin</username>
                    <password>adminadmin</password>
                    <filename>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</filename>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/MissionControl</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven Skip Tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your POM it seems you run on JBoss AS 7.1 which comes with the Bean Validation 1.0 API. Such container-provided APIs [take precedence](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7) over types provided in the deployment itself. I think you're best off using an EE 7 compatible server such as WildFly 8 (Beta1 has recently been released).

Comment: Is there another way of making JBoss use the latter  Bean Validation API? I can't switch servers. Production is running on JBoss AS 7.1

Comment: I think in this case I'd use the proprietary API for method validation which is part of Hibernate Validator 4.2 (which is contained in AS 7). The standardized API in BV 1.1 is quite similar so you should be able to update later on without too much trouble.

Comment: What about excluding the Validation-api-1.0.0.GA module that comes with JBoss AS 7 it from loading at all. Prevent automatic dependencies from being added, as it says in the link you included in your answer?

Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566694/javax-xml-stream-xmlstreamexception-parseerror-at-row-col2-1-jboss-deploy

Comment: I don't think that this is going to work out. You'd need to update the BV provider (HV 5) as well but there are other modules in AS 7 which depend on HV 4.x.

Comment: I think I understand you now, I can follow this example from your blog http://hillert.blogspot.com/2011/12/method-validation-with-hibernate.html

Comment: Thank You very much, I followed your example from your blog and everything is working well :-)

Comment: Great that it is working now. To give credit where credit is due, this isn't my blog, it's from another Gunnar :-)

Comment: Oops my bad. Thank You both. But you gave me direction as well :-) Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have a wrong version of the Bean Validation specification on the classpath. Are you sure that you have Bean Validation 1.1 on the classpath and there there is no 1.0 version on the classpath as well. ExecutableValidator got introduced in Bean Validation 1.1.

Comment: I have it as a dependency, I have updated my question with the pom.xml, the weird thing is I don't get this error if I run it on a Junit.