# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/validation/Validator.forExecutables error Hibernate 5 and Validation API 1.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jax-rs, cxf, hibernate-validator

I created a simple web service WAS 8.5. (JAX-RS & Apache CXF)
Below is my sample configuration.

- hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final
- validation-api-1.1.0.Final

  ```
  <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
      <ref bean="validationInInterceptor" />
  </jaxrs:inInterceptors>

  <jaxrs:providers>
      <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
      <ref bean="exceptionMapper" />
  </jaxrs:providers>

  <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      <ref bean="olaWebServices" />
  </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

  <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
      <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
      <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
  </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
  ```

When I execute in my local I can see my wadl. But when I execute my path

```
http://localhost:9080/olaRs/searchBook
```

It throws error:

```
 E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet cxf: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/validation/Validator.forExecutables()Ljavax/validation/executable/ExecutableValidator;
at org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationProvider.getExecutableValidator(BeanValidationProvider.java:154)
```

sample of my code using

```
public class sampleParam {
    @Size(min=3)
    private String name;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSuchMethodError javax.validation.Validator.forExecutables() but the Junit works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537605/nosuchmethoderror-javax-validation-validator-forexecutables-but-the-junit-work)

Comment: I already checked that comment. As I have indicated above, I have correct version of the two jars. The link duplicate provided has hibernate 5.x and validation api of 1.0.x. Mine is hiberbate 5.x and validation 1.1.x. which is just correct but still I do encounter the same issue. Thanks

Comment: As the linked issue says, the problem is there is probably a container-provided version that takes precedence.